# .css files rejecting changes

Tags: css, reactjs, gulp

I am using WebStorm IDE for my React project. I am trying to modify app.css files for changing design. But every time I build or execute the project, it rejects all changes made and gets minified. I have tried running code in VS code also, but no use. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess your using gulp to build your css ? You should look if your css has no error, or something like that, anyway could you be more specific ?

Comment: Yes,I am using gulp.But there is no error in my css,because when I run it using sublime.It works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Check out the [tour] and also "[mcve]" and well as "[ask]".  You can [edit] your question to show the code you've tried so far, and what's not working in it (errors, expected behavior, etc).

Answer (score 0):

ReactJs uses scss and when you build your project gulp compiles your scss files to app.css. If you want to make changes in your CSS, you have to do it in you .scss files then it will be compiled to your app.css

Comment: Okay,but in my app.scss,I can find only import statements of different files.
How  to work with it?Do I need to change those files?

Comment: Yes, you have to make changes in the files which are being imported in app.scss.

Comment: Okay,I'll try this and get back.

Comment: In that case you have to mark this answer helpful. :p